# Genymotion can't install gapps

Tags: android, google-apps, genymotion

I'm trying to install Gapps on genymotion. WHat I do..
Create new device, android 7.1.0... After I start it, I click on Open GAPPS in top right angle of phone, and I've got error "Failed to dowload Open GApps". Does anyone know reason for this?

You have image there:
[image]

Comment: We (Genymobile) are aware of this. This is a bug on our side. We are about to release a new version of Genymotion to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been fixed in Genymotion 2.12.1, which has just [been released](https://www.genymotion.com/download/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are still unable to do it, you can also download Open GApps from sourceforge and install manually.

Go to https://opengapps.org/

In the page that opens select architecture as x86 (this is the architecture that genymotion uses).

Then select the Android version that you want and the GApps variant and then finally click on the download button. A zip file will get downloaded.

Now run your virtual Android device. Select and drag the zip file inside the virtual device. It will ask for your permission to flash the android device. Click OK.

After the flashing is done successfully, restart your virtual device and update it.

Comment: Good idea. Worked!

Answer (score -3):

1. Download New Version of Genymotion
2. Extract the files
3. Copy & Past to the same folder where Old Version is located
4. Then click " Open GApps"
5. Done

Enjoy